# date comparison problem

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a string named `date` . `date` holds date like `jan 10`.  I want to check whether it falls between two dates or not . Example `jan 10` is between `dec 10` and `feb 10`.  How can I do this task?

Comment: Can you please use Upper Case letters at the start of sentences and proper nouns?

Comment: Are all three dates in string?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your dates to DateTime and than use the [JPLabs extension method Between](http://jp-labs.blogspot.com/2010/01/my-extension-method-colllection.html).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace JpLabs.Extensions
{
    public static class ComparableExt
    {
        static public bool Between<T>(this T actual, T lower, T upper) where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            return actual.CompareTo(lower) >= 0 && actual.CompareTo(upper) < 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Manish

This should do it if you are using c#

```
public bool IsDateBetweenOtherDates(DateTime startDate,DateTime endDate, DateTime testDate)
    {
        return startDate < testDate && endDate > testDate;
    }
```

Comment: you could use extension methods too.

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "jan 10";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MMM dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
if (dt < new DateTime(dt.Year, 12, 10) && 
    dt > new DateTime(dt.Year, 2, 10))
{
     // the date is between 10 feb and 10 dec.
}
```

Comment: Your first date cast isn't quite right. It'll cast it to the same year as his date. You need dt.Year - 1

Comment: Given that the input has no year component the `ParseExact` method will use the current year and if you use `dt.Year - 1` the condition will **never** be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DateTime.TryParse()` to turn your string into a DateTime, which can then be compared to other dates.

```
DateTime minDate = // minimum boundary
DateTime maxDate = // maximum boundary
string input = "January 10, 2010";
DateTime inputDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out inputDate))
{
   if (inputDate > minDate && inputDate < maxDate)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    public bool IsDateBetweenOtherDates(DateTime startDate,DateTime endDate, DateTime testDate)
    {
        return startDate < testDate && endDate > testDate;
    }
```

Comment: Consider explaining why this code should work. This makes the answer more useful to others and is more likely to have it be appreciated.